# Is it possible to generate a unique random alphanumeric code consisting of 5 characters using Informix or standard sql?

Tags: sql, random, informix

I'm using informix IDS server, and I have this table `table1` :

```
Column name          Type                                    Nulls

ad_code              char(5)                                 yes
ad_value             smallint                                yes
```

I would like to generate a random, unique code for field `ad_code` (and then store it in the `ad_code` field)  of table `table1` using sql.
Is it possible ?

It would be enough, alternatively, an alphanumeric code sequnziale, es. 00001 ... 00009 ... 0000A unique

I have tried something like this, in the case of hexadecimal values in the 
field `ad_code`:

```
select  first 5  ('0x'||NVL( l.ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1
from table1 as l
left outer join table1 as r on
('0x'||NVL( l.ad_code, '0'))::INT + 1 =
('0x'||NVL( r.ad_code, '0'))::INT
where       
r.ad_code is null ORDER BY 1 ASC;
commit;
```

but is very slow despite having created an index on `ad_code`.

Comment: Does Informix have sequences?

Comment: I don't know, but prefer do not use sequence built in db

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. IIRC Informix was an early fork of Postgres. Nevertheless, informix (like postgres) has [`SERIAL`, `BIGSERIAL` and `SERIAL8`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1408.htm#ids_sqs_1408) (last 2 are synonyms).

Comment: @Bohemian: in that case I would use a sequence and convert the sequence number to hex-values. That way you get guaranteed uniqueness (as much as possible with only 5 digits) and alpha-numeric values as well

Comment: @a_h agreed. Converting to base 16 comes for free via `hex()`. Converting to base 36 would be ideal, but AFAICT there’s no built-in function for that. You could write a stored proc to do it though.

Comment: @Bohemian: Informix was not 'an early fork of Postgres'.  And (depressingly) SERIAL8 and BIGSERIAL are not synonyms — use BIGSERIAL and not SERIAL8.  Informix does have support for sequences.

Comment: What alphabet do you want to use?  `[a-z0-9]`? `[A-Z0-9]`?  `[A-Za-z0-9]`?  Something else?  Using `CHAR(5)`, you don't get all that many distinct values.  Moreover, generating a random sequence is not too hard (though not as easy as you'd like), but ensuring uniqueness _is_ harder.  Will you have a unique constraint on `ad_code`?  You can go down the "keep trying to insert new random values until you don't hit a unique constraint violation", but that isn't necessarily very efficient as you start to reach the limit on the number of codes.  If there's only one code unused, it could take ages!

Comment: You probably already know this, but I wanted to mention that random != unique.You could get multiple identical random numbers. Not sure if this is important to you or not. If you want random **and** unique you would need to generate the ID then check it against all previous IDs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what the diff between bigserial and serial8? The doc says they’re the same.

Comment: @Bohemian: Which documentation says that?  There's a difference — SERIAL8 occupies 10 bytes on disk; BIGSERIAL only uses 8 bytes.  They can store the same value range; that's true.  But the underlying types are different, and the on-disk storage is different.

Comment: @jon This [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1408.htm#ids_sqs_1408) lists both as one entry, implying they are synonyms, although there's a note that *BIGSERIAL has storage and processing advantages over SERIAL8.*

Comment: @Bohemian: The two types are both said to be able to store the same range of values, which is correct.  However, the Informix ESQL/C Programmer's Guide mentions that the [`ifx_int8_t`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0166.htm) type is a structure with 2 unsigned 32-bit integers plus a short integer, which would occupy 12 bytes in memory on most machines, and occupies 10 bytes on disk.  The `int8` type is more like `int64_t` in C `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate 15-bit random numbers using this pair of stored procedures:

```
-- @(#)$Id: random.spl,v 1.2 1997/12/08 19:31:44 johnl Exp $
--
-- Simple emulation of SRAND and RAND in SPL
-- Using random number generator suggested by C standard (ISO 9899:1990)

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_setseed(n INTEGER)
        DEFINE GLOBAL seed DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT 1;
        LET seed = n;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_random() RETURNING INTEGER;
        DEFINE GLOBAL seed DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT 1;
        DEFINE d DECIMAL(20,0);
        LET d = (seed * 1103515245) + 12345;
        -- MOD function does not handle 20-digit values...  Dammit!!
        LET seed = d - 4294967296 * TRUNC(d / 4294967296);
        RETURN MOD(TRUNC(seed / 65536), 32768);
END PROCEDURE;
```

You can use those numbers to generate a sequence of alphanumeric characters, with more or less finesse.  A simple approach uses the random number modulo the number of alphanumeric characters (do you want `[A-Z0-9]` or `[a-z0-9]` or `[A-Za-z0-9]`, or something else), and select a character each time.  There is potential for unequal distributions if you are not careful (because if there are 32768 possible random numbers, and you have 36 possible characters, 8 of characters will have a 911 out of 32768 chance of being selected, while the other 28 will only have a 910 out of 32768 chance of being selected (and the problem is bigger if you use 62 characters — lower-case, upper-case and digits).  There are ways to deal with that if it is a problem.

Here's the simple-minded, slightly skewed approach at work:

```
-- @(#)$Id: randomstring.spl,v 1.1 2018/08/27 16:43:59 jonathanleffler Exp $
--
-- Generate a random sequence of characters from given list

CREATE FUNCTION sp_randomstring(str VARCHAR(255), num INTEGER)
    RETURNING VARCHAR(255) AS random_string;
    DEFINE r VARCHAR(255);
    DEFINE i INTEGER;
    DEFINE n INTEGER;
    DEFINE j INTEGER;
    LET r = "";
    LET n = LENGTH(str);
    FOR i = 1 TO num
        LET j = MOD(sp_random(), n) + 1;
        LET r = r || SUBSTR(str, j, 1);
    END FOR;
    RETURN r;
END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 20);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 21);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 22);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 23);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 24);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 24);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 23);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 22);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 21);
EXECUTE FUNCTION sp_randomstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 20);
```

Sample output:

```
087TTLGDMSNXMAFL7PJG
cklp14dfk66308lxkzjyu
6JDTOJLC47UE9GWSHRBH55
gwpmrfwwwcykgqbn494bmeh
TNY3U3VMHN01UZS1GV4LOF0K
tm38v8qwqj6o0vrsh9gbb0w6
YF6QP6NT3VK5ARTFDL1N32B
vrb9pvww5cw6egsz9tniex
9OIY799Z694DBENBDFSFE
1gkj5adm3bswlo26wd5i
```

I didn't set the seed, so that code generates the same sequence every time.  You might use a sequence to generate a new seed each time, or you might do something else to seed the generator.  The seed is private to each session.

Comment: @Thanks for you answer, but I have a field of char and I need that uniqueness is guaranteed

Comment: The code shown can generate 5-character strings as easily as strings with 20+ characters.  Ensuring uniqueness s much harder as I explained. You have to keep a record somewhere of which values have already been used and check each new value against that list.

Comment: @famedoro: So based on the 5 char code examples in your question, it looks like you wish to only use `[A-Z0-9]` uppercase alphanumeric characters? If true, then you are using a 36 character set, 5 at a time. So we're looking at 36!5 (36 factorial 5) which produces 376,992 unique combinations. Is this sufficient for your needs?.. So every time your proc generates a random combo, it has to do a lookup in the table where you are storing the unique combos to see if the newly generated random combo already exists. If it exist, loop back to generate another combo. if not exist, then store it.